# How to draw this wavy circle using Android canvas?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

Trying to draw this wavy circle using Android canvas. Have tried using a Bezier curve, but not getting any good results.

[image: Example of desired result]

Comment: See: [Parametric equation of sinusoidal curve around semi-circle for radius 0.75](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3341257/118981) the desmos graph in the answer should help visualize. Alternatively consider drawing one slice of the pie/clock face and rotate 12 times.

Comment: There is an open source app that named Read You. They achived this using CornerBasedShape. Here is [implementation](https://github.com/Ashinch/ReadYou/blob/main/app/src/main/java/me/ash/reader/ui/component/base/CurlyCornerShape.kt)  and [usage](https://github.com/Ashinch/ReadYou/blob/main/app/src/main/java/me/ash/reader/ui/page/settings/tips/TipsAndSupportPage.kt#L137)

Comment: Thanks guys. @EnesKayıklık that was exactly what I was looking for. I was able to convert it into a path and add it to a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I think the new [Androidx graphics-shapes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/graphics) library is what you want.
See the related [Medium article: The Shape of Things to Come](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/the-shape-of-things-to-come-1c7663d9dbc0).

Also, for Jetpack Compose, there is a [GitHub repository here](https://github.com/pz64/RoundedStarShape-JetPack-Compose) creating those shapes.

As a side note, I was looking for the name of this shape and I think it is called:

- **scallop**
- **sunflower**
- **star**
- **clover**
- **rounded polygon**
- **wavy circle**
- **zigzag circle**